# Qt Application (release) crashes when DLLs are added to its directory

Tags: c++, windows, qt, dll

I'm working on Windows. I created application with QtCreator (4.0.3) with Qt 5.7 and builded Qt 5.7.0 MinGW 32-bit. Via QtCreator it worked with "debug" version and "realese" version. I thought all was fine so I tried to lunch it directly (.exe file) but it requested some .dll (mostly Qt5Core.dll), but as soon as I copied tohse to its folder applicatio nstarted to crash. As long as DLLs were palced in direcotry - even previously working build woud crash when lunched via QtCreator. Basicly - DLLs's presence made it all worse and crash, but without them - it's imosible to lunch application via .exe file.

Is there any solution or logical reason for those issues?

When i added Qt5Core.dll to directory and tried to lunch .exe i saw message :

"Cant find entry point to precedure z_inflate in library Qt5Core.dll"

Comment: I hope someone has a time to find a good duplicate question about deploying Qt5 app on Windows, there should be a few... Anyway, http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/windows-deployment.html should explain what you are missing!

Comment: And the tool you definitely do want to use is `windeployqt`, it comes with Qt SDK.

Comment: That's a requested topic in SO documentation, I proposed a [first draft](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/proposed/changes/88156?draftId=74160)